# Are there differences between ubuntu server 12.04 and 14.04 in network configuration during the installation?

Tags: networking, server

I decided to turn my old laptop into a server just to learn about servers and linux.

I installed the ubuntu server 12.04, I chose my wireless connection during the installation and I installed the Basic Ubuntu Server and OpenSSH packages. After the installation I just needed to run `dhclient -r` and `/etc/init.d/networking restart` to get access to internet.

After, I did the same to install the server 14.04. Although, `wlan0` wasn't showing with `ifconfig` and neither was displayed at the `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Is there a reason why 12.04 saved the connection configuration from installation and 14.04 didn't, or did I do something wrong?